# Add timestamp column in mysql

Tags: mysql, timestamp

SQL Statement:

```
ALTER TABLE `Trade`.`details` 
ADD COLUMN `datetime` TIMESTAMP(3) NOT NULL DEFAULT TIMESTAMP(3) AFTER `Result`
```

> ERROR 1064: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '(3) AFTER `Result`' at line 2

i am new to mysql any help.Please

Answer (score 0):

timestamp doesn't need length, also you are defining a default value but provided a datetype instead !!

here is what I mean

```
ALTER TABLE `Trade`.`details` 
ADD COLUMN `datetime` TIMESTAMP NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP AFTER `Result`
```